# Lifecycle callbacks on detached entity not called when merged back

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I've observed an unexpected behaviour in my JPA project.

Basically, my entities have their `modified()` method called on every update  as follows:

```
@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
private void callback() {
    modified(); // sets a java.util.time.Instant
}
```

which works normally.

At some point, I had to detach the entity, did some change, then merged it back; but the callback isn't called.

Is this a bug, or part of the documented specification?

I'm using EclipseLink, if it matters.

---

EDIT: Tracked it down to a completely different problem, which is irrelevant in  this question.

Comment: Can you attach your transactional method where you do all the operations including the merge? May shed some light on things

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i did some tests and this is what i found and what my opinion on the case is (im using JPA 2.1).

The only time, the `merge()` operation can invoke an event listener is when it is invoked on a new entity which is not yet persisted. It then acts as a `persist()` operation itself and the `@PrePersist` annotated classes are called.
This is correct behavior as of specification:

> The `PrePersist` and `PreRemove` callback methods are invoked for a given
>   entity before the respective `EntityManager` `persist` and `remove`
>   operations for that entity are executed. For entities to which the
>   merge operation has been applied and causes the creation of newly
>   managed instances, the PrePersist callback methods will be invoked for
>   the managed instance after the entity state has been copied to it.

Now what you are doing is modifying already existing entity and the only listener that can be invoked is `@PreUpdate / @PostUpdate`.
Though as of specification you have:

> Note that it is implementation-dependent as to whether PreUpdate and
>   PostUpdate callbacks occur when an entity is persisted and
>   subsequently modified in a single transaction or when an entity is
>   modified and subsequently removed within a single transaction.
>   Portable applications should not rely on such behavior

In my opinion you are following the scenario "entity is modified and subsequently removed". Removed meaning from the `PersistenceContext` when it is detached in your case, in which case the behavior is unpredictable.
After some tests i confirm that the listener method is not called in such case.

I could not find any additional configuration that can enforce this behavior in any way.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Not it front of my PC to test, but the detach, change and merge are all in the same transaction. (can't recall, but i think `merge()` is called via method with `TransactionAttribute.REQUIRES_NEW`, should it matter?)

Comment: And the detach is before any change.

Comment: Like i said, it would be beneficial, also for other users to see the transactional code, especially that its not a common case with that new transaction taking place

Comment: The answer is great. But I tracked it down to a complete different problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, change the method from private to public and it worked.

The interfaces are targeting public methods at runtime.